# how can i fix the errors I put them under comments?

Tags: java, inheritance, listiterator

I dont understand why am i getting an error when i am using the listIterator?
the **spot** where i got the error is follow by a comment.

this is my code:

```
   /**
      Returns an iterator for iterating through this list.
      @return an iterator for iterating through this list
  */
   public ListIterator<String> listIterator()
   {  
      return new LinkedListIterator();
      // error here it says: Type safety: The expression of type 
      // LinkedList.LinkedListIterator needs unchecked conversion to conform
      // to ListIterator<String>
   }

   class Node
   {  
      public Object data;
      public Node next;
   }

   class LinkedListIterator implements ListIterator 
   /* here also it says:The type LinkedList.LinkedListIterator must implement
     the inherited abstract method ListIterator.previousIndex() when i implement 
     the listIterator it says:ListIterator is a raw type. References to generic
      type ListIterator<E> should be parameterized*/
```

I dont know how to fix them so any help will be taken. thank you

Comment: Perhaps a good beginner's book on Java or the going through the Oracle tutorials would be a good investment.

Answer (score 3):

In your first method

```
public ListIterator<String> listIterator()
   {  
      return new LinkedListIterator(); // error here it says: Type safety: The expression of type LinkedList.LinkedListIterator needs unchecked conversion to conform to ListIterator<String>
   }
```

Your Return type is generic ListIterator but you are returning Non Generic LinkedListIterator.
In Response you are getting just warning Its not an Error you can simply remove it by adding..

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ListIterator<String> listIterator()
   {  
      return new LinkedListIterator(); // error here it says: Type safety: The expression of type LinkedList.LinkedListIterator needs unchecked conversion to conform to ListIterator<String>
   }
```

Secondly when you add your unimplemented method you are getting another warning which is not error.

```
class LinkedListIterator implements ListIterator
```

ListIterator is not generic you can make it generic.i.e `ListIterator<String>`

and you can also remove this warning by informing the compiler you know that let it be as it is by

```
 @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
class LinkedListIterator implements ListIterator
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error

```
LinkedList.LinkedListIterator must implement the inherited abstract method ListIterator.previousIndex()
```

because `LinkedListIterator` needs to implement ALL of the methods defined in the `ListIterator` class. Until you do that, your `LinkedListIterator` type doesn't actually exist.

Comment: Would be great if you and @user1270995 could merge your answers, since both parts are needed.